# Check if ArrayList size has been changed after updating

Tags: android

I am building an app that contains an `ArrayList` 
and Alarm Manager is checking if `ArrayList` Size Has changed.
so my question is how to check if `ArrayList` Size has changed after update ?

Comment: So what is the problem? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the size of the ArrayList as variable in Shared Preferences. Check at startup.

After an update the value in Shared Preferences will be the size for the old list.